# ITRF 2014 at Epoch 2010.00 and ITRF2014 at Epoch 2018.60?

Tags: coordinate-system

What is the difference between ITRF 2014 at Epoch 2010.00 and ITRF2014 at Epoch 2018.60 ?

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to compare here. Are you looking for transformations to another reference frame? The coordinates of the defining stations of the ITRF shift over time based on the tectonic plate model, and other national or local reference frames can move relative to ITRF over time.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should probably do some reading at the [ITRF website](http://itrf.ensg.ign.fr/ITRF_solutions/2014/) like the General Concepts. The link goes to the ITRF2014 home page.

ITRF2014 was defined using the coordinates of a set of positions as they were in 2010.0. That is, January 1, 2010.

Epoch just means date, and is given in decimal years. Epoch 2018.60 corresponds to the 219th day of the year or August 7, 2018. NASA has a [calendar for this](https://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/Craig.Markwardt/doy2018.html).

As I said, the control network (set of locations) has positions published at 2010.0. Each location also has a published velocity model which predicts how the location's coordinates will change over time.

Using the published velocity model/equation, you can "move" the location to 2018.60.

Here's an example for Fort Davis, Texas, USA (near McDonald Observatory). The web app is only giving ITRF 2008 or earlier coordinates, unfortunately, for this point.

```
DOMES NB    SITE NAME   ID   SOLN
40442M008   FORT DAVIS  7850    1

X             Y             Z            SIGMA x  SIGMA y  SIGMA z
-1330008.363  -5328391.584  3236502.652    0.002    0.002    0.002

Vx      Vy      Vz         vx       vy      vz
m/y     m/y     m/y        m/y      m/y     m/y
-0.0128 0.0004  -0.0051    0.0001   0.0001  0.0001
```

The coordinates are in 3D Cartesian / geocentric format. The first line of numbers are in meters, while the velocities are in meters per year. Keeping the coordinates in XYZ space means that it's much easier to calculate the changes in position.

Comment: Dear Sir,

 Many thanks for your valuable reply.

Thanks & Regards
Prabakaran.S

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER FROM AUSPOS:

The differences mainly depend on which plate your site is in. For ITRF2014 reference frame sites current epoch coordinates can be obtained by coordinates in epoch 2010  + velocities x time difference between 2010 and current epoch.